# Angular Material - Text now showing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean

I just started using Angular for university purpose and I wanted to start easy so I just copied some stuff for the official Angular material page into my editor.
(Used bower to install angular-material "bower install angular-material")

This is my code (image, because they don't like HTML code here):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4gu5.jpg

The button is showing up, but the fancy "click on" animation doesn't work and I cannot see the button description neither!

It was me who add the "." in front of every src/href (the button is not there on the original angular example page, but without the dot, the font won't even be in material style but just standard e.g. Arial)

Where is the problem, did I forget something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They like HTML code here,a lot more than a link I need to follow to even understand the question

Answer (score 0):

You are using the controller `MainCtrl` in your application, but you never actually created a `MainCtrl` in your JS. You also reference `YourController` in your JS, which is also not declared anywhere.

I recommend to read the error messages angular is giving you in the console.